# Why I can't see SharePoint-2013 updates( Available Patches) through Windows Updates?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Why I cant see SharePoint-2013 updates(Patches) through Windows Updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change settings for Windows Update to include other Microsoft products in Windows Update settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The windows update include only the SharePoint security fixes ! not the full patch update , 
If you need to see the SharePoint patches you should get it by navigating to

> Central administration > Upgrade and migration > Check product and
>   patch installation status

For more details check [SharePoint CUs and Windows Update – Important Update!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/02/26/sharepoint-cus-and-windows-update-important-update/)